# Enabling authentication in swagger

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui

I created a asp.net core empty project running on .net6. I am coming across an issue when I am trying to enable authentication in swagger. Swagger UI runs as expected, the only issue is whenever I click on the `Authorize` green button on the swagger UI it will pop up but say Unknown Security definition type and give me two options Authorize and Close. It does not show under Available authorizations Bearer(http,Bearer) and allow me to enter a jwt value. I ran into this [article](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/) that goes over bearer authentication but it isn't much help for me. Am I missing something in the `.AddSwaggerGen()`?

[image]

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options => 
{
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Scheme = "Bearer",
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Name = "Authorization",
        Description = "Bearer Authentication with JWT Token",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http
    });
    options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Id = "Bearer",
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
                }
            },
            new List<string>()
        }
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();
......
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `Scheme` should be `"bearer"` (lowercase b)

```
Scheme = "bearer",
```

Comment: I gave this a shot but it still produces the same issue. I then made `.AddSecurityDefinition("bearer",...)` and changed `Id = "bearer"` thinking that would solve it but it still does the same issue too. What do you think could be the cause of it?

Answer (score 1):

You have used add authorization before defining your security definition.
First define security definition & then use add authorization